# .NET 4,0 Listeners change

Tags: .net, config

I upgraded some legacy console application from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0.  I am getting a runtime error on the first line of Main() that "type is not a recognized attribute".  It is originating from the .exe.config file in the following section:

```
        <listeners>
            <add name="RHIOListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\Htp\RHIOListener.log"/>
            <remove type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
```

The problem is with the "remove type" line.  It looks like the attribute should be "name" instead.  I'm not sure what to do.  There doesn't seem to be an explicitly created, "named" DefaultTraceListener.  Is this line even necessary?

Comment: I removed the line, ran the application, and not only did the world not blow up, but it did not error out.  I still wouldn't mind a comment if anyone wants to help me understand what the story is here.

Comment: Run your application inside the debugger (don't forget to set the debugger to break on every exception), you'll see where it blocks, probably why and what it did before..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't remove by `type`, you have to do it by `name`.

Error message is because, [according to .config schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w11c2b46.aspx), the only attribute allowed for `remove` node is `name`. Try one of the following:

```
<listeners>
    <add name="RHIOListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\Htp\RHIOListener.log"/>
    <remove name="Default"/>
</listeners>
```

Or:

```
<listeners>
    <clear/>
    <add name="RHIOListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\Htp\RHIOListener.log"/>
</listeners>
```